# Alternative to SlideshowPro Director?

Tags: php, image, content-management-system, photo-gallery

I have used [SlideshowPro Director](http://slideshowpro.net/products/slideshowpro_director/), along with it's PHP API, as an Image Management System on several sites in the past. The backend is incredibly well-designed and easy to use, and the system stores original quality uploads, so you can request specific images sizes and have them dynamically created without much trouble.

However, it seems that SlideshowPro Director, especially the API, is not receiving as much attention from the developer as it used to, and I am tired of running into problems with no solutions.

Is anyone aware of any PHP-based Image/Portfolio Management Systems that have similar capabilities and are similarly well-designed? Open-source or commercial are both fine.

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, there are several. 
My favourites would be:

**Proprietary:**

- [jAlbum](http://jalbum.net/en/purchase): 19€ selfhosted onetime license. Hosted if needed. Generates HTML+Flash galleries on your computer, no PHP. [Themes](http://jalbum.net/en/skins/popular). Latest release: 10/2012
- [Clickbooq](http://www.clickbooq.com/pricing.php): 24/mth, only hosted. [Themes](http://www.clickbooq.com/gallery_featured_users.php). Latest update: 11/2012

**Free & OpenSource** (all PHP based):

- [ZenPhoto](http://www.zenphoto.org/): Powerful; paid support, slick admin interface  [Themes](http://www.zenphoto.org/page/search/theme-compatible), [demo page](http://www.zenphoto.org/demo/?themeSwitcher=default).  Latest release: 11/2012
- [Simpleviewer](http://www.simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/): Minimalistic, more a plugin than a full management system. [Demo page](http://www.simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/examples/modern/). Latest release: 09/2012
- [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/gallery/g3demosites/): Powerful, rather complicated, community support. Latest release: 09/2010

However, I don't know what kind of API functions you are looking for.
Most suggestions are under current development (as of 11/2012).

> I would recommend **ZenPhoto** to people who know their PHP,
>   **jAlbum
>   hosted** to people who do not know PHP.